# Scikit-multiflow EvaluatePrequential

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to get the prediction from the evaluator but i only get none in variable `my_pred`. Nevertheless, the `evaluator.evaluate` code works fine. So , i can't understand what is wrong.

```
from skmultiflow.data import SEAGenerator
from skmultiflow.trees import HoeffdingTreeClassifier
from skmultiflow.evaluation import EvaluatePrequential
# Set the stream
stream = SEAGenerator(random_state=1)
# Set the model
ht = HoeffdingTreeClassifier()
# Set the evaluator
evaluator = EvaluatePrequential(max_samples=200,
                                n_wait=1,
                                pretrain_size=1,
                                max_time=1000,
                                show_plot=True,
                                metrics=['accuracy'],
                                data_points_for_classification=True)

n_samples = 0
corrects = 0
while n_samples < 5000:
    X, y = stream.next_sample()
    my_pred = evaluator.predict(X)
    print(my_pred)
    if y[0] == my_pred:
        corrects += 1
    evaluator = evaluator.partial_fit(X, y)
    n_samples += 1

# Run evaluation
evaluator.evaluate(stream=stream, model=ht, model_names=['HT'])
```

Comment: What do you mean "*works fine*"? What is the result?

Comment: For the line of print(my_pred) i get none , but later for the evaluator.evaluate i get the plots and later the result :
HT - Accuracy     : 0.9095

My problem is why i do not get result for my_pred

Comment: The first time the `while` loop runs, you are calling `evaluator.predict()` before `evaluator_partial_fit()`; plus, a `pretrain_size=1` is obviously way too low